# Android: get two inputs from one edit text

Tags: android

I'm now writing a code that accepts two inputs from one `EditText` and shows a `Toast` message with the two inputs.

Here's the code inside the `onCreate()` method.

```
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    etPIN.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            String pin1 = null, pin2 = null;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                pin1 = etPIN.getText().toString();

                tvPINGuide.setText(getString(R.string.confirm_pin));
                etPIN.setText(null);

            }

            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                pin2 = etPIN.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(PINActivity.this, "pin1: " + pin1 + ", pin2: " + pin2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            return true;
        }
    });
```

With this code, it does not seem to proceed to taking to the second step i.e. getting the `pin2`'s value. When I run the code and click the the `Toast` message is like this.

`pin1: 1234, pin2:`

So what should I do to do the following two things?

1. get each `pin1` and `pin2` string values and show them to the `Toast` finally.
2. after getting the second string value and clicking the done button, the soft keyboard hides.

Comment: you really do something strange with your code. First you get text from an EditText: `pin1 = etPIN.getText().toString();`. Then you set the text of EditText to `null`: `etPIN.setText(null);`. And now you get the text from it again `pin2 = etPIN.getText().toString();`, and wonder, why the pin2 is empty. That's because you set it to empty with this line: `etPIN.setText(null);`

Comment: @VladMatvienko So what can be the solution? I'm really new to the programming itself.

Comment: Once you describe what exactly you want, I will try to figure out a solution. Tell me, what you enter in the EditText, and what you want to get as a result

Comment: @VladMatvienko I enter `1234` first and `5678` second, and I get the result with the `Toast` like this - `pin1: 1234, pin2: 5678`. This is what I want to implement.

Comment: so you want to first enter `1234`. then press `done`, then enter `5678`, and then press done again, right?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to declare `pin1` and `pin2` as global variables.
Then change your `onEditorAction` as follows:

```
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pin1)) { //if pin1 is not entered so far
                    pin1 = etPIN.getText().toString();  //then enter it
                    tvPINGuide.setText(getString(R.string.confirm_pin));
                    etPIN.setText(null);
                } else {   //else pin2 is not entered
                    pin2 = etPIN.getText().toString();  //enter it
                    Toast.makeText(PINActivity.this, "pin1: " + pin1 + ", pin2: " + pin2).show();  //and show the toast 
                }

            } 

            return true;
```

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you Vlad.